# Can’t connect to SSH

Tags: ssh, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to get in to the backend of my website in VS Code, but every time I write the password it says

> could not establish connection to ssh.mydomain.dk

I succeeded with log-in in the terminal, but that didn't help much, because I want to see the files and folders visually so I can edit the backend.

It is the right information, but I can't sign in.

I use the remote - SSH plug-in which hasn't been a problem before.

I've reloaded VS Code and checked updated plug-ins. Logged in through the terminal and checked information.

[Img from the config and the terminal]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1vlR.png

[More from the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qmje.png)

[This is the message that I get everytime](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLLXj.png)

Comment: We will need the verbose logs from the server and the client, a screenshot of the ACL for the key if your using Key authentication, and the server configuration file.

Comment: Try this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/72639923 - You can check the documentation here : https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/troubleshooting#_troubleshooting-hanging-or-failing-connections - If the connection works in a "classic" shell / terminal, it is clearly an issue related to VS Code itself.

Comment: `-v` flag in ssh as in `ssh -v ...` will print out detailed logs about what is happening.

Comment: I´ve tried to kill the code server but it didn't work either.. I´ve uploaded three photos from vs code with the config file and the terminal in the section above.

Comment: Did you try to remove the server configuration in VS code and recreated from zero ? - There are probably cache or a config file in VS code for remote connection.

Comment: Yes and I´ve also reset all the settings in vs code, but it still doesnt work

Comment: We need more details about the error you got. Do you have the SSH auth.log file when attempting to connect with VS Code ?